# What is the best way to use argparse when i can, but fall back to getopt?

Tags: python, argparse, getopt

In our shop, we have multiple versions of python installed. 2.4 - 2.7 and 3.1 to 3.5 on Solaris, CentOs and Ubuntu.  I want to use argparse, when i can, but fall back to getopt when it is unavailable.

My current approach is the following.  Thank you.

```
try:
    import argparse
    argparse_in = True
except ImportError:
    argparse_in = False
    import getopt

...

if argparse_in:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("-d", "--date",
                        help="date, i.e., yyyymmdd")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--institution",
                        help="institution id")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbosity", action="count", default=0,
                        help="increase output verbosity")
else:

    options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 
                         'd:i:v', 
                         ['date=', 'institution=','verbososity'])
    for opt, arg in options:
        if opt in ('-d', '--date'):
            data_date = arg
        elif opt in ('-i', '--institution'):
            inst_id = arg
        elif opt in ('-v', '--verbose'):
            verbose += 1
...
```

Comment: That's a fine option. You could [install the backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) on older Python versions, perhaps.

Comment: Maybe fall back on `optparse` since it is more similar to `argparse`?